# reshape2 melt a list of pixel image objects like in reshape

Tags: r, tidyverse, reshape, reshape2

I have a list of pixel image objects from spatstat.geom (see example data below) and want to melt them into one data.frame. I do it with reshape::melt and it works fine. Now, I wanted to do it with reshape2::melt and it throws an error. Why is reshape2::melt behaving differently? Is there another comparatively fast solution for this problem, e.g., in the tidyverse?

```
a <- spatstat.geom::im(matrix(rep(1:3,3), ncol = 3))

tmp <- list(a = a,
        b = a)

reshape::melt(tmp)
```

The output is:

```
# value.x value.y value.value value.optional L1
# 1        1       1           1           TRUE  a
# 2        1       2           2           TRUE  a
# 3        1       3           3           TRUE  a
# 4        2       1           1           TRUE  a
# 5        2       2           2           TRUE  a
# 6        2       3           3           TRUE  a
# 7        3       1           1           TRUE  a
# 8        3       2           2           TRUE  a
# 9        3       3           3           TRUE  a
# 10       1       1           1           TRUE  b
# 11       1       2           2           TRUE  b
# 12       1       3           3           TRUE  b
# 13       2       1           1           TRUE  b
# 14       2       2           2           TRUE  b
# 15       2       3           3           TRUE  b
# 16       3       1           1           TRUE  b
# 17       3       2           2           TRUE  b
# 18       3       3           3           TRUE  b
```

```
reshape2::melt(tmp)
```

This throws the following error:

```
Error in vector(type, length): vector: cannot generate a vector of mode 'NULL'.
```

Comment: I'm not receiving any errors when I run your code. I'm using reshape 0.8.8 in R Version 3.5.3. In general, I would move towards doing these kinds of operations with `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider` from the tidyr package.

Comment: Thanks @TedM. for your comment. I don't get errors with reshape either, but with reshape2. I am using R version 4.2.1, reshape 0.8.9 and reshape2 1.4.4. Have you run the code with reshape2 without error? I like the melt-function, because it is only one line of code. Can you do it with pivot_longer in only a few lines?

Comment: I also get an error with reshape2 but not reshape. `pivot_longer` will require more lines of code, and it can't operate on a list - or you'll have to first convert to a dataframe. If you haven't done so already, I'd encourage you to report this error to https://github.com/hadley/reshape/issues